# show the custom class properties inside the repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

My Repeater is something like this,

```
<img src="Admin/Upload/150/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Car.ImageName") %>" alt="" class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
```

And my custom class is like this;

```
public  class GetCarProperties
{    
    public Car_Car { get; set; }
    public CarPrice _CarPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the one above 
but this failed, how can I achive this, I mean, get the car picname from my list and put it inside the repeater?

Comment: nobody  knows the answer? interesting

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems with your code:

Your `img` `src` property has a syntax error, try something along the lines of the following:

```
<img src='Admin/Upload/150/' + '<%#
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"_Car.ImageName") %>' alt="" class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
```

and there is no `ImageName` property in your class, just `_Car` and `_Price`.

Comment: I am sorry it was my mistake,solution is related to the _CAr class

Comment: do u know how can I show image which is boolean come from my class.which if it is true I wanna show one image ,if false wanna show another image.thank you boddy

Comment: I'd suggest keeping your binding simple and just adding another property in your class with the appropriate logic i.e. in the property's GET determine which image to return based on the boolean property.